# Shutting down elasticsearch completely?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have found a number of posts about shutting down a node or a cluster of nodes, but what about stopping all elasticsearch processes on a machine?   Even after shutting down all nodes (curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown') I find that I still have a java process running org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.  The only way I've found to stop that (on Linux) is to find the process ID with ps and kill it.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Speaking anecdotally, I've never once met a java daemon that quit reliably. I'm so un-trusting of them that I make a habit of checking the output of `ps aux | grep java` to ensure that no dangling processes remain.

Comment: @EEAA So, are you saying you think the _shutdown URL *should* have stopped that process, but didn't?  (It very reliably stays up.)